# Laravel 5.8 withCount() is ignoring my where statement

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to find the count of specific compliance items for candidates on a agency system.

When I use with() it returns 1 result which is correct, but when I use withCount() it returns the number of all compliance items and ignores the where statement.

Candidate Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Candidate extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'candidates';

    public function complianceItemsActive()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CandidateComplianceItem', 'candidate_id', 'id')
            ->where('valid_until', '>=', date('Y-m-d'))
            ->orWhereNull('valid_until');
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Candidate;
use App\Client;
use App\WorkVacancy;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TableController extends Controller
{
    public function vacancyCandidateSearch(Request $request, $vacancy_id)
    {
        $vacancy = WorkVacancy::with([
            'client',
            'requiredCompliance' => function ($query) {
                $query->leftJoin('compliance_items', 'client_compliance.compliance_id', 'compliance_items.id');
            }])
            ->findOrFail($vacancy_id);

        $required_compliances = $vacancy->requiredCompliance;
        $required_compliances_array = [];

        if (count($required_compliances) > 0) {
            foreach ($required_compliances as $required_compliance) {
                array_push($required_compliances_array, $required_compliance->compliance_id);
            }
        }

        // with() returns 1 result, withCount() returns them all
        $data = Candidate::with([
            'complianceItemsActive' => function ($q) use ($required_compliances_array) {
                $q->whereIn('compliance_id', $required_compliances_array);
            }])->withCount([
            'complianceItemsActive' => function ($q) use ($required_compliances_array) {
                $q->whereIn('compliance_id', $required_compliances_array);
            },
        ]);


        $data = $data->paginate(10);
        $data->setPath('#');
        $data->view = null;
        $data->count = count($data);

        return \Response::JSON([
            'data'       => $data,
            'count'      => count($data),
            'total'      => $data->total(),
            'per_page'   => $data->perpage(),
            'pagination' => (string)$data->links(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Response (Note `compliance_items_active_count` and `compliance_items_active`):

```
{"data":{"current_page":1,"data":[{"id":1,"forename":"John","other_names":null,"surname":"Smith","gender":"Male","address_1":"Address1","address_2":"Address2","address_3":null,"postcode":"POST CODE","country":"England","telephone":"0987654321","mobile":"1234567890","email":"email@email.com","notes":null,"account_holder_name":null,"sort_code":null,"account_number":null,"bsrn":null,"ni_number":"123","passport_number":null,"issuing_country":null,"nok_relationship":null,"nok_name":null,"nok_telephone":null,"nok_mobile":null,"consent_accepted":1,"consent_notes":null,"candidate_details_source":null,"mode_of_travel":"Walk","travel_range":"5","min_pay":8,"payment_per":"hour","deleted":0,"created_at":"2019-07-11 13:19:43","created_by":1,"updated_at":"2019-07-22 10:31:07","updated_by":1,"compliance_items_active_count":4,"compliance_items_active":[{"id":5,"compliance_id":3,"candidate_id":1,"reference":null,"additional_info":null,"valid_until":null,"created_at":"2019-07-22 12:07:36","updated_at":"2019-07-22 12:07:36"}]}],"first_page_url":"#?page=1","from":1,"last_page":1,"last_page_url":"#?page=1","next_page_url":null,"path":"#","per_page":10,"prev_page_url":null,"to":1,"total":1},"count":1,"total":1,"per_page":10,"pagination":""}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong but I think it might have something to do with the additional clauses in your relationship. I would suggest nesting those clauses so that the they don't conflict with clauses you add on later:

```
public function complianceItemsActive()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\CandidateComplianceItem', 'candidate_id', 'id')
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('valid_until', '>=', date('Y-m-d'))->orWhereNull('valid_until');
        });
}
```